# profinite completion and linear representations of finitely presented groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group. It is clear that if the profinite completion $\widehat{G} $ of $G$ is finite, then any finite dimensional complex linear representation $\rho: G\to \text{GL}(m, \mathbb{C})$ is finite, i.e., $\rho(G)$ is a finite group. For the converse, is there a counterexample for such $G$ such that any finite dim representation $\rho$ is finite, but $\widehat{G}$ is a infinite group?

Comment: *"It is clear that"* is rather *"It is a clear consequence of Malcev's theorem that"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there exists such a finitely presented group.

Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact arithmetic lattice in a product of $\ge 2$ rank 1 groups simple groups (with trivial center) over locally compact fields of finite characteristic. So $\Gamma$ is finitely presented (it is even CAT($0$)). By Malcev, $\Gamma$ is residually finite. By Kazhdan-Margulis, $\Gamma$ is just-infinite: all normal subgroups in $\Gamma$ except $\{1\}$ have finite index. By Venkataramana's superrigidity, every finite-dimensional complex representation of $\Gamma$ has a finite image.

---

My initial answer was conditional answer:

Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{PSp}(n,1)$, $n\ge 2$. This is a non-elementary hyperbolic group. Hence it is known that for many $x\in\Gamma-\{1\}$, the quotient $\Lambda_x=\Gamma/\langle\!\langle x\rangle\!\rangle$ is non-elementary hyperbolic.

It is also known (superrigidity) that every linear proper quotient of $\Gamma$ is finite. Hence, every linear quotient of $\Lambda_x$ has a finite image. Accordingly

1. either $\Lambda_x$ has an infinite profinite completion, hence answers your question
2. or $\Lambda_x$ has finite profinite completion, and hence there exists a non-residually-finite hyperbolic group. The existence of such a group is a famous open problem.

I'm not sure that any well-accepted conjecture predicts which of these properties holds (this might even depend on $x$).

Comment: Thank you for the nice example!

Answer (score 7):

Yes if you weaken to finitely generated. Take an infinite finitely generated torsion group that is residually finite like the Grigorchuk group.  By a theorem is Schur any finitely generated torsion linear group is finite.  I am not sure of the general case.

Comment: The question asks for a finitely *presented* example. :)

Comment: It is unknown if there are finitely presented infinite torsion groups.

Comment: Sorry. You are right

Comment: But I'll leave this up since it might be useful

Comment: I think your answer is worth keeping, though. Perhaps the OP can clarify how important the "finitely presented" hypothesis is to them.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks for your example! I am actually interested in fundamental groups, so the "finitely presented" condition is necessary for me.